# Can I download and install into another ubuntu partition?

Tags: dual-boot, drivers, partitioning, updates

The drivers in my Ubuntu were broken after an update (Nvidia driver, the driver for wireless and even the driver for mouse I think) and can't even use the OS properly. What I did is, I installed another Ubuntu as partition in order to try access and recover my files from the original. I found out that there was a way to access the original OS (partition) and run commands in it using chroot, however, I think the commands are still running in the original OS' environment. I can't download updates since the driver for wifi is broken.

What I want to do is download the updates in the new OS, and apply them into the old. Is there any way I can do this? Thanks a lot

Comment: have you tried loading the old installation using recovery mode?

Comment: Just boot from the old kernel. You can access older kernels from the grub menu. Although, an update shouldn't break nvidia drivers properly installed through apt-get.

Answer (score 0):

Normally `chroot` would do the trick, as you said.

Mount the partition with the old Ubuntu and then `sudo chroot /path/to/old/ubuntu/rootfs`

Now you should be able to apply all changes to your old Ubuntu installation.

You can also use a Live-DVD/USB to chroot into your installation.

Answer (score 0):

The chroot procedure are as below. you must firstly bind `/proc`,`/dev` and `/sys` to old OS, then chroot and download updates.

```
sudo mount -o bind /proc "/path/to/oldUbuntu/rootfolder"/proc
sudo mount -o bind /dev "/path/to/oldUbuntu/rootfolder"/dev
sudo mount -o bind /sys "/path/to/oldUbuntu/rootfolder"/sys
```

And now chroot:

```
sudo chroot /path/to/oldUbuntu/rootfolder /bin/bash
```

And then you can enter any command you want on old ubuntu :)